# Laravel 8 and Backblaze B2 CURL Error could not resolve host

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, backblaze

I am trying to setup my Laravel application to upload to [Backblaze B2](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/cloud-storage.html) using the [S3 Compatible API](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/docs/s3_compatible_api.html).  I've setup my .env items

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=key1
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=key2
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-001
AWS_BUCKET=bucketname
AWS_ENDPOINT=s3.us-west-001.backblazeb2.com
```

When I try to upload using this `Storage::disk('s3')->put('/images/covers', $request->file('thumbnail'));`

I receive the following error

```
Could not resolve host: bucketname. for http://bucketname./bucketname/
images/covers/rbvl5SL3SiEzxsaUfEG9uMW7TIAPPu9gaFNWxlbG.jpg"
```

I'm unsure as to where to proceed. I tried changing the `AWS_ENDPOINT` to include my bucket name,, but didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
AWS_URL=bucketname.s3.us-west-001.backblazeb2.com
AWS_ENDPOINT=https://s3.us-west-001.backblazeb2.com
```

Comment: Do you mean `backblazeb2 ` rather than `amazonaws`?